# Unable to create login session for LinkedIn in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, linkedin-api

able to launch the app to create session but after login to app the `LISDKSessionManager` succuess block not get called

```
[LISDKSessionManager createSessionWithAuth:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:LISDK_FULL_PROFILE_PERMISSION, nil]
                                         state:nil
                        showGoToAppStoreDialog:YES
                                  successBlock:^(NSString *returnState) {
                                      if(returnState){
                                       NSLog(@"%s","success called!");

                                      }
                                      if (returnState) {
                                          [self updateControlsWithResponseLabel:YES];
                                      }
                                      // NSLog(@"%s","success called!");
                                      LISDKSession *session = [[LISDKSessionManager sharedInstance] session];
                                      NSLog(@"value=%@ isvalid=%@",[session value],[session isValid] ? @"YES" : @"NO");
                                      NSMutableString *text = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:[session.accessToken description]];
                                      [text appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@",state=\"%@\"",returnState]];
                                      NSLog(@"Response label text %@",text);
                                      _responseLabel.text = text;
                                      self.lastError = nil;
                                      // retain cycle here?
                                      [self updateControlsWithResponseLabel:NO];

                                  }
                                    errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                                        NSLog(@"%s %@","error called! ", [error description]);
                                        self.lastError = error;
                                        //  _responseLabel.text = [error description];
                                        [self updateControlsWithResponseLabel:YES];
                                    }
     ];
```

Comment: Is `errorBlock` called? If yes, was does says the error?

Comment: no errorBlock not get called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally notice that linkedIn SDK login only works in iPhone not in iPads

Answer (score 0):

In your AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation 
  {
    return [LISDKCallbackHandler application:application openURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];
  }
```

and in your button action method call this:

```
    NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:LISDK_BASIC_PROFILE_PERMISSION, nil];
   [LISDKSessionManager createSessionWithAuth:permissions state:nil showGoToAppStoreDialog:YES successBlock:^(NSString *returnState)
    {
      NSLog(@"%s","success called!");
      LISDKSession *session = [[LISDKSessionManager sharedInstance] session];
      NSLog(@"Session : %@", session.description);
   } errorBlock:^(NSError *error)
   { 
     NSLog(@"%s","error called!");
  }];

  // call this to fetch basic information of user logged in .   
   -(void) getRequest:(NSString*)token
   { 

    [[LISDKAPIHelper sharedInstance] getRequest:@"https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~"
                                    success:^(LISDKAPIResponse *response)
      {
        NSData* data = [response.data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSDictionary *dictResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
        NSLog(@"Authenticated user name : %@ %@", [dictResponse valueForKey: @"firstName"], [dictResponse valueForKey: @"lastName"]);
       } 
    error:^(LISDKAPIError *apiError)
    {
      NSLog(@"Error : %@", apiError);
   }];
  }
```

Comment: no even in this code no success or error block gets called , i set the debugger in both AppDelegate and button action , AppDelegate debugger not even gets called

Comment: Is your info.plist file ok?? You need to set LIAppID and add these two "linkedin-sdk" and "linkedin-sdk2" inside LSApplicationQueriesSchemes.

Comment: Also add your linkedin app id inside URLTypes ---> URLSchemes

Comment: Instead of Full_Profile_Permission try Basic_Profile_Permission

Comment: i also tried linkedin-sdk sample code in their code it also success block not gets called, is their any other way to create session for linkedIn and fetch user info and redirect to my app.

Comment: Look the above thing works for me, you should verify your app credentials on linkedin's developer portal, and recheck your info.plist

Comment: can u please share screenshot of your info.plist

Comment: what should i exactly put in OAuth 2.0
Authorized Redirect URLs